# TaskCommitDenied (Driver denied task commit) for job: <Job #> partition: <partition #>, attemptNumber:<Attempt #>

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

One of our spark is running continuously in loop(never ending) with "TaskCommitDenied (Driver denied task commit) for job: 1985, partition: 886, attemptNumber: 7213" error message. This is happening for 2 jobs(I found it in sparkUi). And I observe that the "attemptNumber" is very high.

Please find the below screenshot for the logs that contain exact error.

logfile screenshot with error:

[image: logfile screenshot with error]

I am assuming driver killed the Fileoutputwriter asynchronously on executor, but executor is still trying to finish the task to write the file on hdfs. Is this what happening? If yes, any suggested fix?

Comment: Some information which would be helpful: how did you run the job in terms of number of executors and executor cores, memory,....? How is the cluster setup? Have you executed the job while other jobs were running?